# Ocserv static tun device name for each user

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, network-monitoring, openconnect

Ocserv assigns dynamic interface names based on TUN device name. For example if tun device name is vpns, users connect via vpns0, vpns1 , vpns2 and ...
Everytime a user opens a new session, a new interface name is assigned and because most tracking systems use interface names, I cannot figure out how much traffic a user has used for example in the past week. Is it possible to configure ocserv to assign static interface name for each ocpsswd user?